# how to groupby a dataset after fill it by a column data

Tags: ado.net

Hi all
I have a dataset that fill it with some data that shows cont object id in date 
i want groupby it on year of date.
this is my code :

```
 string ctInc = @"  select COUNT(inc.HSEIncidentId) number, datepart(year,inc.Date)AS displayDate
                           from dbo.HSEIncident inc
                           group by displayDate";
        SqlCommand cmdInc = new SqlCommand(ctInc, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapterInc = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdInc);
        DataSet dsInc = new DataSet();
        adapterInc.Fill(dsInc);
```

but sql riase an error that say "displayDate" is not valid column in table.
how can i group by it.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
select COUNT(inc.HSEIncidentId) number, datepart(year,inc.Date) AS displayDate
                           from dbo.HSEIncident inc
                           group by datepart(year,inc.Date)";
```